# ipython shell not opening

Tags: python, ipython, pdb, ipdb

I am working in a virtual environment.

Following is the requirements.txt:

```
behave==1.2.5
fake-factory==0.5.3
parse==1.6.6
parse-type==0.3.4
pbr==1.8.1
selenium==2.53.5
six==1.10.0
stevedore==1.10.0
virtualenv==13.1.2
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.6.0
wheel==0.24.0
pyhamcrest
requests==2.9.1
ipdb
pyyaml
```

I am using `python-3.5`. Ipython version is `5.0`.

I have put an `ipdb` in my code to debug. When control reach that point, it stops there but the `ipython` console doesn't open up.

Also if i use `pdb`, then it works fine.

So I believe the problem is with `ipython` which I am not able to figure out.

Am I missing anything here. What could be the possible problem.

Comment: I have ipython3 already installed. Both point to the same ipython version. @MaNKuR

Comment: but its missing in the requirements.txt file, is it install in env or system?

Comment: Its in the virtual environment